# Check intermediate ancestor type of object

Tags: c++, inheritance, rtti

Some places in our code make extensive use of 'dynamic_cast` do check the type of a given object:

```cpp
    if (dynamic_cast<Foo*>(bar))
        return "foo";
    else
        return "not-foo";
```

In some specific section of the code, we decided to switch to `typeid`, but we ran into a problem: we're checking an object against an arbitrary ancestor, not to its concrete type:

```cpp
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

struct Base
{
    virtual ~Base() {} // enable vtable
};

struct Derived : Base{};

struct DerivedAgain : Derived{};
struct OtherDerived : Derived{};

int main() {
    Base* b = new DerivedAgain;
    // if (typeid(*b) == typeid(Derived)) // will print false
    if (dynamic_cast<Derived*>(b))
        std::cout << "true\n";
    else
        std::cout << "false\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to check if `b` is `Derived*` without `dynamic_cast`?

P.S.: I'm aware this might be indicative of some larger problem with the design of the code, but I want to know *specifically* how to make this kind of check.

Comment: `dynamic_cast` is the way to make this kind of check, why dont you want to use it?

Comment: from what I've seen, `dynamic_cast` has a very large overhead and `typeid` seems to be a better option with less overhead. maybe the overhead just means what I want is complex

Comment: btw the polymorphism way in this example would be to add a vritual mehtod to `base` that returns `false`, and `Derived` overrides it to return `true`, though when you need to check the type then it is already non polymorphic

Comment: what overhead do you refer to?

Comment: I'm aware I can this can be solved with a polymorphic method, but that's intrusive and it assumes I can change the classes

Comment: @Romário There is no feature provided by the language to achieve this. You need to implement it as part of the classes. But, usually, having to check the dynamic type of an object is code smell and often points towards a design error. If you need to check if an object is some specific dynamic type for something to work, then that object it isn't actually fulfilling the expectation that it fully conforms to the requirements of the base type. Or the function is inaccurate that it is expected to work on a base type, when it actually needs on of its derived types.

Comment: Of course `typeid` is cheaper, it doesn't have to examine inheritance chains! There are no free lunches. The behavior you seek is exactly the reason `dynamic_cast` has additional cost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `dynamic_cast` **is what I want** in this specific case, since it is the only thing in the language that will actually examine the dependency chain of the object.

---

That said, it's worth mentioning that, as I said in the question and many people said in the comments, having to use `dynamic_cast` *may* be an indicative of a larger design problem in the code. One possible solution is using a polymorphic method instead:

```cpp
// with checking
int doThing(Base* b)
{
    if (auto d = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(b))
        return stuff(d);
    if (auto d = dynamic_cast<OtherDerived*>(b))
        return otherStuff(d);

    return 0;
}

// with polymorphism
int doThing(Base* b)
{
    return b->stuff();
}

// stuff is a virtual method defined in Base, Derived and OtherDerived
struct Base
{
    virtual int stuff() const {}
};

struct Derived : Base
{
    int stuff() const override { return stuff(this); }
};

struct OtherDerived : Base
{
    int stuff() const override { return otherStuff(this); }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to go around `dynamic_cast`, with some manual work, if you have relatively few types:

- add a `static constexpr/const int mytypeno` member to each class with a distinct prime number (this can be done automatically)
- add another `static constexpr/const int mytypecompatibility` member, which is:

  - for base (topmost classes) the same as `mytypeno`
  - for classes that has base classes, the product of their `mytypeno` and all base classes' `mytypeno`

Then you can check if a class is a descendant of another as: `descendant.mytypecompatibility % base.mytypeno == 0`. This idea was originally proposed by Bjarne for a quick implementation of `dynamic_cast<>` with full access to all sources (vs. local solutions). It's also relatively little intrusion as you only take two `static constexpr` members, thus no per-object overhead and you don't force virtual table to be used.

Comment: *"(this can be done automatically)"* I'd be curious how you achieve this automatically.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux If you don't need it to work in `constexpr` and static initialization, then simply assign these a generator that has a local static with the largest number (i.e., `... mytypeno = GetNextMyTypeNo()`). If you need it there, then code generators or a (semi-manual) lookup from a type list which fails if you don't include the new type.